# How do I simplify this sum?

Tags: summation

What technique should I use for simplifying

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k-1}{k(k+1)(k+2)} ?$$

Comment: Use partial fractions to simplify the denominator.

Comment: It doesn't help with the further calculation :(
Also, n -> ∞ as n is natural number.

Comment: Really, looks like Alan is using this approach in his solution.  Albeit in a clever way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe that
$$k-1 = k + (k+1) - (k+2).$$
Therefore,
\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k-1}{k(k+1)(k+2)} &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k(k+2)}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k(k+1)} \\ &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+2}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+2}\right)-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)\end{align}
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yep. Now I get it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let $$g(k)=\dfrac{k-1}{k(k+1)(k+2)}=f(k+1)-f(k)$$ where $f(m)=\dfrac{am+b}{m(m+1)}$ where $a,b$ are arbitrary constants

so that using  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series,

the partial sum
$$\sum_{k=1}^ng(k)=g(n+1)-g(1)$$

Compare the coefficients of $k^2,k$ and the constants to find $a,b$

Finally set $n\to\infty$